# How to search for a specific number in a string?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that prompts the user to find a specific file on their computer. The files are named like this "**Daily Operations Report - DAY MONTH YEAR**".

I need to make sure that the file chosen has the same date as today. I know how to compare two dates and find if they are equal or not.

How do I find a number in a string?

```
'Previous code not relevant to the question

Dim strFilePath, fName As String
Dim wdDoc As Object

strFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If strFilePath = "False" Then End  'Pressed cancel

fName = strFilePath

Set wdDoc = GetObject(fName)
```

After executing the above code, I can find the name of the file in (wdDoc), for example:

```
 MsgBox wdDoc
```

I get:

> Daily Operations Report - 21st December 2019

How can I compare the file to today's date? I believe comparing the number of days would be easier and faster than comparing days, months and years for the two dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but here is one. It takes the filename and converts it to a date. What you do with that date for comparison is up to you.

```
Function GetDateFromFilename(sFilename As String) As Date
  Dim sFullDate As String
  Dim sDay As String
  Dim sNum As String
  Dim nDig As Integer: nDig = 1

  ' get rid of the extension just in case it exists
  sFilename = Split(sFilename, ".")(0)

  ' get just the date part for processing
  If Instr(sFilename, " - ") = 0 Then
    Msgbox "Filename not in proper format"
    GetDateFromFilename = CDate("1/1/1990")
    Exit Function
  End If
  sFullDate = Split(sFilename, " - ")(1)

  ' get the first digit of that
  sNum = Left$(sFullDate, nDig)

  ' loop thru the characters until there is an alpha character
  Do While nDig <= Len(sFullDate)
    If IsNumeric(sNum) Then
      sDay = sDay & sNum
    Else
      ' found the first alpha, so we are done here
      Exit Do
    End If
    ' check the next character
    nDig = nDig + 1
    sNum = Mid$(sFullDate, nDig, 1)
  Loop

  ' build a string that correctly resembles a date (month first)
  sFullDate = Split(sFullDate)(1) & " " & sDay & " " & Split(sFullDate)(2)

  ' or build a string that correctly resembles a date (day first)
  ' sFullDate = sDay & " " & Split(sFullDate)(1) & " " & Split(sFullDate)(2)

  ' convert it to an actual date and return it
  GetDateFromFilename = CDate(sFullDate)

End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
Dim dtFileDate As Date
dtFileDate = GetDateFromFilename("Daily Operations Report - 21st December 2019")
' show just the day number
MsgBox Format$(dtFileDate, "d")
```

<sub>**Note:** If your filename string is not in this exact format, there is a good chance it will error, but your question implies it will **always** be in that format.</sub>